# Which is the correct method of declaration CSS class? and what is different from following methods?

Tags: html, css

Which is the correct method of declaration CSS class? and what is different from following methods?

1) *div.classname { }*  
2) *.classname { }*

Comment: a homework ? ... http://galjot.si/combining-css-selectors

Comment: [CSS .class Selector official website](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) <- click that and make some research

Comment: a simple google search and you will get a ton of tutorial/explanation better than all the answers you can get here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are valid, but used in different ways:

- `.classname`: Styles will be applied for every element with class `classname`
- `element.classname`: Styles will be applied for every **type of this element** element **with** class `classname`

---

Example:

```css
.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="class"></div>
<section class="class"></section>
<p class="class"></p>
```

Comment: By creating this snippet you introduced another important factor which is specifity. the second one is overriding the first